# Is there a multi-channel music file/encoding format that iCloud Music Library will accept?

Tags: itunes, icloud, audio, music

I've created some multi-channel (surround sound, 5.1) tracks of my own. My initial attempts at encoding them (AAC/ALAC as AC3/DolbyDigital) all work well. They sounds great and spatial audio works a treat with them playing in Music app on macOS.

BUT, Music app refuses to upload them to iCloud Music Library (status: ineligible) and so here I am asking a question:

Q: is there a multi-channel file/encoding format that can be synced to iCloud?

> The goal is for me to add my music and it be playable from all my Apple devices (iPhone, iPad, Apple TV, Mac, with/without AirPods Pro)

> Workaround: I can upload the files to a folder in iCloud Drive and play them using an app like VLC, but I'd prefer to use Music app